# how to add input values to npm modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an API module but I tested this script and `configl` is started giving an error. How do I fix this problem?

```
const index = require("./index");

exports.shorten(configl) = function() {
    const shortenlink = config
  };

exports.postlink = shortenlink;

module.exports = shorten;
```

Comment: if you want test this module [click here](https://npm.runkit.com/js-tltc)

Comment: You have a typo, `configl` v `config` which will cause a `ReferenceError: config is not defined`.

Comment: You've got a number of issues here. `exports.shorten(configl) = ...` is incorrect syntax. `configl` is not the same as `config` and it looks like you're declaring a variable inside a function, then trying to export it from outside the function. I have no idea what this module is supposed to accomplish, but it's severely broken.